# Adding Row at TOP Using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have something this excel data frame.

[image]

need to below. I was looking another articles but, I can't find like this.... someone help please.

[image]

Comment: Is the data in an existing Excel workbook or a dataframe in your current code?

Comment: Adding a description to the "top" of your dataframe will not work - pandas needs clear rows and columns to work with, not loose text descriptors. Consider using a dictionary to store your data and description as two different entries.

Comment: this existing excel workbook @norie

Comment: really? god...  @jfaccioni